# Haskell, HIP library, decode function

Tags: haskell, hip

Please help me understand how to use [the `decode` function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hip-1.5.6.0/docs/Graphics-Image-IO-Formats.html#v:decode) from the HIP library.

```
class ImageFormat format => Readable img format where
  decode :: format -> B.ByteString -> Either String img
```

I don't understand the first parameter, what should it be? Example would help.

Comment: As the name suggest, it's the format. The instances help a bit in understanding it better

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thank you very much for editing the question, your way is better.

Comment: `JPG` (of type `JPG`) is an example of a value that is an acceptable first argument because there is an instance of `Readable something JPG`.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Your suggestion generates the following error: `Ambiguous type variable ‘img0’ arising from a use of ‘decode’
      prevents the constraint ‘(hip-1.5.6.0:Graphics.Image.IO.Base.Readable
                                  img0 JPG)’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include
        b :: Either String img0 (bound at src/Termonad/App.hs:396:7)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘img0’ should be.`

Comment: Well "use a type annotation to specify what ‘img0’ should be" looks like a specific suggestion to follow. There is more than one instance, e.g. `Readable (Image VS RGBA Word8) GIF` and `Readable (Image VS RGBA Double) GIF`. You need to specify somehow which one you want.

Comment: You probably need something like `decode GIF argument2 :: Either String (Image VS RGBA Word8)` to disambiguate.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI or @chi Could you please provide a full code example cause I am still getting an error while following your suggestion: `let b = decode (PNG :: (Readable (Image VS YA Word8) PNG)) iconByteString`. I am definitely doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type classes are a little bit messy when you have fat arrows. The intention of typeclass `Readable` is to defined the set of types which can be read from a given `ImageFormat`, where an `ImageFormat` is a typeclass too. A little verbose but It'll be clear below; bear with me.

```hs
class ImageFormat format => Readable img format where
  decode :: format -> B.ByteString -> Either String img
--          |         |               |- returns codification error or the something of type img.
--          |         |- This is the raw bytestring of the image
--          |- This is a type which implements the ImageFormat typeclass  (see below)
```

Now, you can check in the documentation the instances of each type class. For example `ImageFormat` has these [instances](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hip-1.5.6.0/docs/Graphics-Image-IO-Formats.html#t:ImageFormat).

[image]

So, your first argument should be one of those. But not only so, you also need to be sure that the pair `img format` implements the `Readable` typeclass. For example `Readable` has these instances (among others):

- `Readable (Image VS RGB Double) PNG`
- `Readable [Image VS RGB  Double] (Seq GIF)`

You can interpret these as "from a `PNG` I can read and `Image VS RGB Double` and from a sequence of `GIF` I can read `[Image VS RGB Double]` (list of images)". But more important there is no(!!) instance

- `Readable [Image VS RGB Double] PNG`

Which means that you **can't** read a list of images from a PNG.

That being said, how do you use the `decode` function?. well, we know that the first argument should be one of the instances of `ImageFormat`, so lets pick `PNG`

```hs
my_bytestring :: ByteString
my_bytestring = ... whateve

wrong_my_image = decode PNG some_bytestring
-- You could think that this read an Image from a PNG but, which image should we pick??
-- There are many instances for this. For example:
-- Readable (Image VS RGB Double) PNG  reads a PNG as a Vector of Doubles in the RGB color space
-- Readable (Image VS RGBA Word8) PNG  reads a PNG as a Vector of 8-bits unsigned integers in the RGB with alpha color space
-- Readable (Image VS Y Word16) PNG    reads a PNG as a Vector of 16-bits unsigned integers in the YUV color space
-- etc...

right_my_image_1 :: Either String (Image VS RGB Double) -- For example
right_my_image_1 = decode PNG my_bytestring

right_my_image_2 = decode PNG my_bytestring :: Either String (Image VS RGB Double)
-- Notice that you must(!!) specify the type you want to read to with explicit
-- annotations. Wheter the annotation is in two lines or one line is up to you.
```

Comment: It's perhaps worth mentioning that you used both `PNG` the type and `PNG` the value constructor here. It so happens that `PNG` and most of the other `ImageFormat` types have only one constructor, so they're basically used as _phantom types_ - although there are also ones with nontrivial runtime information, like [`InputFormat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hip-1.5.6.0/docs/Graphics-Image-IO-Formats.html#t:InputFormat). Frankly I find interface a bit haft-hearted; I'd prefer having `format` as a pure type-level entiity and using existentials for choosing dynamically.

Comment: Shouldn't the result of `decode ....` have type `Either String ...` ?